# PostgreSQL Trigger and rows updated

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I am trying to update a table according to this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER alert 
AFTER UPDATE ON cars
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_cars();
```

Trigger Function :

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_cars()
RETURNS 'TRIGGER' 
AS $BODY$
BEGIN 
IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
UPDATE hello_cars SET status = new.status 
WHERE OLD.ID = NEW.ID;
END IF;
RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The trigger works fine. When the `cars` table is updated, the `hello_cars` table is updated but the status column in each row is updated and contains same new status! It must be updated according to a car ID.
I think my problem is in condition: `WHERE OLD.ID = NEW.ID;` but I can't tell what's wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`OLD` and `NEW` are aliases to the rows which fired the trigger. So when you execute a statement like

```
UPDATE cars SET status='xyz' WHERE cars.id = 42;
```

then the trigger function will execute

```
UPDATE hello_cars SET status='xyz' WHERE 42 = 42
```

The part `42=42` is always true. So each row in `hello_cars` is updated.

You really want something like

```
 [...]WHERE hello_cars.id = OLD.ID
```

or a little shorter

```
 [...]WHERE id = OLD.ID
```

But you also need to think about what happens, if the initial update changes `cars.id`. In this case `OLD.ID` is not equal `NEW.ID`. What should happen in the table `hello_cars` in this case? But that's another question.

Comment: @Shadin: You're welcome. Please see the [FAQ/How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) how to accept the answer which helped you most.

Answer (score 6):

`OLD.ID` and `NEW.ID` are referencing *values* in the updated row of the table `cars` and thus (unless you change the ID in `cars`) will always evaluate to true and therefor all rows in hello_cars are updated.

I think you probably want:

```
UPDATE hello_cars
   SET status = new.status
WHERE id = new.id;
```

This assumes that there is a column `id` in the table `hello_cars` that matches the `id` in `cars`.